# Howt to sort sections by an array

Tags: wordpress, sorting, switch-statement

I have sections in my page and i want to sorting with an array.

```
<section class="section-1">
    //section fields
</section>

<section class="section-2">
    //section fields
</section> 

<section class="section-3">
    //section fields
</section>
```

And i am trying this section by array.

```
$sw = array(a, b, c);
swithc($sw){
    case a:
    echo '<section class="section-a"></section>';
    break;

    case b:
    echo '<section class="section-b"></section>';
    break;

    case c:
    echo '<section class="section-c"></section>';
    break;
}
```

if array is a,b,c then sort frontend like this
section-a
section-b
section-c

or

if array is b,a,c then sort like
section-b
section-a
section-c

But it not working. Where i am wrong?

Comment: On what basis you want to sort and let know if it's ok to sort in the front-end?

Comment: Edited my question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What i understood is you need the case according to array element count.

If i am not wrong than try below code.

```
$sw = array(1, 2, 3);
 $countArray = count($sw);
 switch($countArray){
 case 1:
 echo '<section class="section-1"></section>';
 break;

 case 2:
 echo '<section class="section-2"></section>';
 break;

 case 3:
 echo '<section class="section-3"></section>';
 break;
}
```